# becomeFirstResponder not working in Editing Did End Event

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, xcode7.3, becomefirstresponder

I am checking the textfield value. If it will empty then the focus will stay in same textfield else it will move to another textfield. So, Here is some code which I implemented. But, currently it's not working.

```
- (IBAction)verifyDisplayName:(id)sender {
        if ([_displayName.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            [_displayNameField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else
        {
            _displayNameVerified = YES;
        }
}
```

Please give me suggestion related to my Query.

Thanks

Comment: Have you debug code ? And check for the _displayName that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Check variables;
Here you checking `_displayName.text`
Next you are setting `[_displayNameField becomeFirstResponder];`

I think it would be better to use smthg like this:

```
_displayName.text.length > 0 //In this case you can validate length of your name, if conditions will change
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can you provide more code? property of your controls for example